# error auth dependency when using IoC Container injection

Tags: php, laravel-4, package

I'm using IoC Container injection in my controller and when i use MultiAuth package.
like this:

```
<?php namespace Controllers\MyNameSpace;

use Ollieread\MultiAuth\AuthManager as Auth;

class AuthUserController extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        if ( $this->auth->user()->check()) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }

        return 'NOoOo ...';
    }
```

i recieve this error:

`Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Ollieread\MultiAuth\AuthManager`

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to have load via the IoC, that's kind of defeating the purpose of the facades system.